# concatenate values in column in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Very difficult to choose a title for this question, but here is the detail. Let's use mtcars for this example.

Let's transform this into a data.table

```
m<-as.data.table(mtcars,keep.rownames = T)
```

What I want is to concatenate in a single character all the cars that have a particular carb value. So I did the following:

```
A<-m[, list(list(rn)), by = carb]
```

And it partially works... for carb=4 I get:
Mazda RX4,Mazda RX4 Wag,Duster 360,Merc 280,Merc 280C,Cadillac Fleetwood,

But Those are not all the cars with carb=4
It seems that the answer is trimmed somehow...

I hope someone can help with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line: `A<-m[, list(list(rn)), by = carb]` created a column in your data.table of class "list":

```
class(A$V1)
[1] "list"
```

It makes it quite hard to manipulate. In addition, the result gets trimmed a little when printing.
An easier and better solution - to concatenate into one string:

```
A<-m[, paste(rn,collapse=","),by=carb]
A
   carb                                                                                                                                           V1
1:    4 Mazda RX4,Mazda RX4 Wag,Duster 360,Merc 280,Merc 280C,Cadillac     Fleetwood,Lincoln Continental,Chrysler Imperial,Camaro Z28,Ford Pantera L
2:    1                                                        Datsun 710,Hornet 4 Drive,Valiant,Fiat 128,Toyota Corolla,Toyota Corona,Fiat X1-9
3:    2     Hornet Sportabout,Merc 240D,Merc 230,Honda Civic,Dodge Challenger,AMC Javelin,Pontiac Firebird,Porsche 914-2,Lotus Europa,Volvo 142E
4:    3                                                                                                        Merc 450SE,Merc 450SL,Merc 450SLC
5:    6                                                                                                                             Ferrari Dino
6:    8                                                                                                                            Maserati Bora
```